# Test class error on Apex class UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: apex, community, apexrest

I am new to Salesforce Technologies.

I am writing a test class for my APEX class.

My test class has the following code.

```
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert acc;

    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.AccountId = acc.Id;
    con.LastName = 'contact';
    con.FirstName ='Test';
    con.Email = 'test11@test.com';
    insert con;

    User u = new User();
    u.ProfileID = '00e70000001NyjLAAS';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u.FirstName = 'contact';
    u.LastName = 'contact';
    u.Username = con.Email;   
    u.CommunityNickname = 'Awesome';
    u.Alias = 'EXT_'+string.ValueOf(Math.random()).right(4);
    u.Email = con.Email;
    u.IsActive = true;
    u.ContactId = con.Id;
    insert u;
```

When running the test I am getting the following error:

**UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []**

And the line number of error was the line number of `insert u;`

I even tried to add a UserRole as

```
User user = [SELECT UserRole.ID, UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE email = 'someone@domain.com'];
```

AND

```
u.UserRole.Name = user.UserRole.Name;
u.UserRole.ID = user.UserRole.ID;
```

But then it gave me the following error

**System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object**

I assume it is for user.UserRole.Name

Can anyone help me to get rid of this error??

**Thank you very much in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error. as the error says `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []` So currently your user is a account owner so assign role to your user so one solution is assign a role to your user because it is also required when you create in live environment.

or second option is you would need to create a test user which has a role defined, and then runas test user. With this all the account or contacts which are getting created will have Owner as this test user, and now when in your code the community user from your code it wont throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tushar.
I have a question regarding changing the account owner role.
Do we have to do it programmatically??
I have tried to assign a role programmatically as you can see in second part of my question. Do let me know if I am doing it the wrong way.
Any help is appretiated.

Comment: This did solve my problem.
I created a user (test@test.com) manually from Manage Users in salesforce.
And during creation I explicitly mentioned the User Role and the User License as per required and used the user (test@test.com) in my test classes.
Thanks Tushar.

Comment: @AnKarthik glad to know your problem solved. But instead of creating new user you can give role to your user too.

Comment: @AnKarthik not sure but maybe the user user you are querying don't have any role.

Answer (score 1):

here is the sample code:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account Name');
  insert a;

  Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Contact Last Name', AccountId = a.id);
  insert c;

  User user = new User();
  user.ProfileID = [Select Id From Profile Where Name='Some Profile'].id;
  user.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
  user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
  user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
  user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
  user.FirstName = 'first';
  user.LastName = 'last';
  user.Username = 'test@appirio.com';   
  user.CommunityNickname = 'testUser123';
  user.Alias = 't1';
  user.Email = 'no@email.com';
  user.IsActive = true;
  user.ContactId = c.Id;

  insert user;

  System.RunAs(user) {
    // do all of my tests
  }
```

for more details:
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175522

Answer (score 1):

This error is generated because the user was not assigned a role. 
You will also see this same error (for the same reason) when trying to enable a contact as a partner or customer portal user.

The following sample code demonstrates how to avoid this error:

```
  Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account Name');
  insert a;

  Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Contact Last Name', AccountId = a.id);
  insert c;

  User user = new User();
  user.ProfileID = [Select Id From Profile Where Name='Some Profile'].id;
  user.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
  user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
  user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
  user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
  user.FirstName = 'first';
  user.LastName = 'last';
  user.Username = 'test@appirio.com';   
  user.CommunityNickname = 'testUser123';
  user.Alias = 't1';
  user.Email = 'no@email.com';
  user.IsActive = true;
  user.ContactId = c.Id;

  insert user;

  System.RunAs(user) {
    // do all of my tests
  }
```